# NDK build error in Android Studio finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am working on [OpenCV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV), so for that I am using NDK. But while making a project or making a build, I am getting an error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.
> Process 'command 'C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I am not getting why this is occurring. Below is my *[build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)* code:

```
sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = [] // Disable automatic ndk-build call
}
task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    commandLine "C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd",
            'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
            'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
            'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
            'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: You may also try to use CMake build architecture in latest Android Studio Versions to get rid of such errors. :)

Comment: You mean by editing android.mk and application.mk

Comment: In Android Studio 2.3 you should use integrated externalBuild: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html. You don't need to switch to `CMake`, it fully supports `ndk-build`.

Comment: Regarding the error, can reproduce it from the command line? It will be easier to see the build log in your console. If you can not figure out yourself, post this output here.

Comment: @AlexCohn thanks ! i have to read from developer site and can you please tell me that for using openCv which one is better using NDK or simple openCv java SDK ??

Comment: Add flags to the build to generate more information about the reason for the build failure. Run `gradlew buildNative --info` from your `app` directory. Also try the `--stacktrace` and `--debug` flags if `--info` doesn't help. Then you can share more of your output with us. Another option is to run `ndk-build V=1` from your `app/src/main/jni` directory.

Comment: If your needs are satisfied with javaCV, it is definitely easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by changing the **OPENCVROOT** variable in file *Android.mk* to

```
OPENCVROOT := /pathToYourOpenCVFile/sdk/native/jni
```

which means that you should not write to your top directory as explained in OpenCV tutorials.

I am using [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr) and [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio) 2.3.2.